# How to do testfor with different maps

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

in my map players get given certain maps via command blocks. This works fine but when I try to mimic this with the testfor command, it doesnt work.

I use /give @p minecraft:filled_map 1 2 to spawn the specific map

However, when I do /testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:filled_map 1 2}]} it just says that I didnt match the required data structure

Is this a mishap on my part or is there another way to do this? Appreciate all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number that we're interested in is the 2 in the `/give` command. This is the data value for the map. This corresponds to the `Damage:` field of the NBT tag. Damage is a short, so you must use `2s` to indicate a damage value of 2. So the proper NBT tag for the item is `{id:minecraft:filled_map,Damage:2s}`. Therefore, the final command becomes as follows:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:filled_map",Damage:2s}]}
```

That said, `/give @p filled_map 1 2` doesn't necessarily work in the way you would expect: the damage value 2 will only apply if it has already been created. Otherwise, it'll give the player a map with value 0, then 1. Use F3+H to verify the actual data value of the map that you have. This won't be a problem after the map has been generated.

Comment: I just tried this and it didnt work for some reason, I copied and pasted it right into the command block and it just says that I didnt match the required data structure. The map I have in my inventory is Map #2

Comment: When testing for pre-existing NBT data, you must specify the name, value, and datatype correctly. In this case, the datatype was declared as an integer, when it instead must be declared as a short (`Damage:2s`).

Comment: @B-DigidyDog Hold on, I'm working through some errors in my command structure

Comment: @B-DigidyDog I have fixed and tested all errors that existed previously in my answer, and indicated another possible reason this could be failing that I discovered in my testing.